# Is there any reason to use threading.Lock over multiprocessing.Lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, locking, multiprocessing

If a software project supports a version of Python that multiprocessing has been backported to, is there any reason to use `threading.Lock` over `multiprocessing.Lock`?  Would a `multiprocessing` lock not be thread safe as well?

For that matter, is there a reason to use *any* synchronization primitives from `threading` that are also in `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The threading module's synchronization primitive are lighter and faster than multiprocessing, due to the lack of dealing with shared semaphores, etc. If you are using threads; use threading's locks. Processes should use multiprocessing's locks.

Comment: Not to mention that `multiprocessing` isn't as portable as `threading` is ;)

Comment: In my program, there are multiple threads and processes. Can I use multiprocessing.Lock for thread synchronization also?

Comment: Just as a confirmation, acquiring and releasing 100,000 threading locks takes 0.07 seconds while doing the same with 100,000 multiprocessing locks takes 8.1 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

I would expect the multi-threading synchronization primitives to be quite faster as they can use shared memory area easily. But I suppose you will have to perform speed test to be sure of it. Also, you might have side-effects that are quite unwanted (and unspecified in the doc).

For example, a process-wise lock could very well block all threads of the process. And if it doesn't, releasing a lock might not wake up the threads of the process.

In short, if you want your code to work for sure, you should use the thread-synchronization primitives if you are using threads and the process-synchronization primitives if you are using processes. Otherwise, it might work on your platform only, or even just with your specific version of Python.

Comment: In my program, there are multiple threads and processes. Can I use multiprocessing.Lock for thread synchronization also?

Answer (score 4):

`multiprocessing` and `threading` packages have slightly different aims, though both are concurrency related.  `threading` coordinates threads within one process, while `multiprocessing` provide thread-like interface for coordinating multiple processes.

If your application doesn't spawn new processes which require data synchronization, `multiprocessing` is a bit more heavy weight, and `threading` package should be better suited.

Comment: I understand the difference between threading and multiprocessing.  I was curious why one would want to use threading's synchronization primitives over multiprocessing's.